# speech_recognition with pyaudio string

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

i am working with speech_recognition module.i am able to get proper result by using my Microphone or wav file (in traditional ways like sr.record or sr.listen).but now i want to get the results by using string which is returned by stream.read(chunk) method.i know r.recognize_google() expect sr.AudioData Object.

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
import ctypes
r=sr.Recognizer()
p=pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=2,rate=44100,frames_per_buffer=1024,input=True)
data=[]
while True:
    data.append(stream.read(1024))
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(27)==-32767: #break the loop when press esc
        break
audio=sr.AudioData(frame_data=b''.join(data),sample_rate=44100,sample_width=2)
    r.recognize_google(audio)
```

i was expecting "hello hello hello" but i am get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Grewal\Desktop\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    r.recognize_google(audio)
  File "C:\Users\Grewal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

Comment: Why do you have channels=2, pyaudio only supports mono sound